# CSS hover of table affects both table border and td

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

How do I get the td to get shaded dark green when the mouse hovers over any part of the table?

**IE 6 please.**

Please don't complain about cellspacing, the gmail login box uses it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<head>
    <title>yo</title>
      <style type="text/css">
        .square-mosaic-green {
            border: 5px solid #a6e3a6;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            height:75px;
            width: 75px;   
        }

        .square-mosaic-green td {
            background-color:#a6e3a6;
        }

        .square-mosaic-green:hover    {
            border-color: #00ae00;
        }

        .square-mosaic-green td:hover    {
            background-color: #00ae00;   
        }
      </style>

</head>
<body>

    <table class="square-mosaic-green" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>                    
         </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.square-mosaic-green:hover td {
            background-color: #00ae00;   
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prNGq/)

This won't work under IE6, just like your code. `:hover` is only supported on certain elements in IE6.

Answer (score 3):

Under IE6, you can't use `:hover` on anything but links. If you want to achieve such an effect, you need either to resort to JavaScript, or to place an `<a>` in the cell and make it as big as the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with jQuery

```
$('.square-mosaic-green').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','#00ae00');
    $(this).css('borderColor','#00ae00');
    },
  function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','#fff');
    $(this).css('borderColor','#a6e3a6');
    }                           
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/CqqvP/

I tested it and it works in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

JS is the only way you are going to be able to do this in that version of IE.

```
onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#000';"
```